# Printing Block Markers in Notepad++

Tags: printing, notepad++

Is there a way to print the visual block indicators in addition to the linemarkers in notepad++?

**Example**:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a way to easily print code block lines natively within Notepad++.

According to their documentation for printing, you can turn code line numbers on / off, but I don't see an option to add block lines:

http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Printing_And_Exporting